# Change button graphic color with css

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

Hi want to do a menubar like Twitter where the icon on the menu button, have there color changed on hover.

There is a way to do that in JavaFX + CSS ? (An other way than just change the png file)

that will look like that

```
.button:hover {
-fx-text-fill: red;
-fx-border-width: 0 0 5 0 ;
-fx-border-color:red ;
-fx-png-on-the-button-color: red;      //Need the way to do something like that
```

}

Comment: If you can use an image file for your button graphic that has a transparent background, you can place a rectangle behind it. It's then pretty easy to change the color of the rectangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugly solution of myself

```
.button:hover ImageView {
-fx-effect: innershadow( gaussian , red , 7 , 1 , 1 , 1 );
```

}

with this innershadow of the color you want, the result is pretty cool. that work fine !

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the color of the loaded image. But instead you can just change the image, which has the color prerendered that you want.

```
-fx-graphic: url(http://example.com)
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#labeled.